# Count numbers between zeros using bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, awk

Using bash script, I want to count the numbers between zeros only. Is it possible to use awk? Sorry, i am new to this.

5000000000009228247152000000000000000000003

5000000000006338293700000000000000000000001

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Using [tag:bash] or [tag:awk]? They're different languages. If you share your attempt so far, we may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: user3003001 - does `count the numbers` mean `sum the numbers` or `tally the numbers` or something else? The expected output from that first line could be `1 10 1` or `10` or `12` or `42` or something else so update your question to include the expected output as fedorqui requested.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to provided your expected output, as well as some minimal attempt to solve the problem rather than simply asking for someone else to code for you.

Comment: Related question by same OP: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25396032/1301972

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -Po '0+\K[^0]+(?=0)'
```

gives you:

```
9228247152
63382937
```

### EDIT

If things could be easily done in a single process (awk here is the case), I won't start 2nd process.

#### awk one-liner with count and text:

```
awk -F'0+' 'NF>2{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "text:%s count:%d\n",$i,length($i)}'
```

gives:

```
text:9228247152 count:10
text:63382937 count:8
```

#### awk one-liner only with count:

```
awk -F'0+' 'NF>2{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)print length($i)}'
```

gives:

```
10
8
```

Comment: How about the count of the numbers between zeros?

Comment: @user3003001 added two awk one-liners, pick the one you need

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
echo 5000000000009228247152000000000000000000003 | \
   sed -n -r -e 's/0+([^0]+)0+/\1/' | wc -m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -oP '0+\K[1-9]+(?=0+)' file
9228247152
63382937
```

To count the number of digits,

```
$ grep -oP '0+\K[1-9]+(?=0+)' file | awk -v FS="" '{print NF}'
10
8
```