# count of zeros between the 1st and 14th digit by using grep

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

How to determine the count of zeros between the 1st and 14th digit? By using grep.

```
 500000000000922801808800000000000000000000922891863600000GS5      00*HOME


 500000000000022811740000000000000000000000922811741600000GS5      00*HOME
```

My condition is: if zero_count=12 then move the record to dst_dir
                 else move the record to drp_dir

Comment: You have asked around a dozen questions. Consider accepting them by clicking on the check mark next to the answer if they helped you resolve your question. On the other hand, you can leave a comment if you have any questions regarding the answer.

Comment: @jaypal If it's a duplicate, link to it so it can be closed as such.

Comment: @CodeGnome I would have, his previous question though similar was about counting digits between `0`s.

Comment: Oh i deeply apologize on this.

Comment: The less effort you put into your question the less likely you are to get a good answer, no matter HOW much effort we put into trying to help you. For your own sake, clarify your requirements and add some more useful representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `dst_dir` and `drp_dir` are two output files you want to create, the following `awk` program will do that for you.

```
awk '
NF {
    data  = substr ($0, 1, 14)
    count = gsub (/0/, "", data)
    print > (count==12 ? "dst_dir" : "drp_dir")
}' file
```

Using `NF` we skip the blank lines. We create a subset of your line using `substr` function. `gsub` returns the number of substitution made, so we capture the return value to variable `count`.

Lastly, we test if the `count` is 12. If it is we write the record to `dst_dir` else we write the record to `drp_dir`.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much to your help. But how if the two records given above is in one file, I want to only move the record ( which has count =! 12) to a new file?

Comment: Run the above code it will do that. It will move all the records whose count is `!= 12` to `drp_dir` file. If the count is `= 12` it will move to `dst_dir` file, just like you asked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

A (mostly) Bash solution using [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to get the first 14 characters:

```
file='500000000000922801808800000000000000000000922891863600000GS5'
count=$(echo "${file:0:13}" | grep --fixed-strings --only-matching 0 | wc -l)
if [[ $count -ne 12 ]]; then 
    mv "$file" "$drp_dir"
else
    mv "$file" "$dst_dir"
fi
```

You might also use `head -c` instead if you prefer.