# Replace record in the fourth field using bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

Good day!

Using bash, how can I replace the record in the fourth field by 9010 if the condition below is meet:

- if the zeros between 1st and 7th digit is equal to 5

NOTE: 
  Fixed width

```
 60000123456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   1000
 60000023456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   1050
```

Comment: Look at some of the other post regarding counting zeros like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396032/count-of-zeros-between-the-1st-and-14th-digit-by-using-grep

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, assuming you meant exactly 5 consecutive 0's:

```
awk '/^[1-9]{,2}0{5}[^0]/{$4=9010}1' input
```

Using GNU `sed` without any assumptions:

```
sed 'h;s/^\(.......\).*/\1/;s/0//g;/^..$/{x;s/[^ ]*$/9010/;b};x' input
```

*Gives:*

```
60000123456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   1000
60000023456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   9010
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '!(substr($0,2,5)+0){sub($NF"$",9010)} 1' file
60000123456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   1000
60000023456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   9010
```

Answer (score 0):

Through awk,

```
awk '/^.00000.*/{sub(/^.*$/,"9010",$4);}1' file
```

Comment: OP wants **if the zeros between 1st and 7th digit is equal to 5**

Comment: he wants the line which has 0's in the 2 to 6 positions. He don't care about the first or 7th.

Comment: Your command will not print `9010` if input line is: `01000023456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   1050` even though it has 5 zeroes between position 1 and 7.

Comment: What makes you think OP needs this even though OP wrote: **if the zeros between 1st and 7th digit is equal to 5**

Comment: zeros between 1st and 7th digit is equal to 5 == `anynumber00000anynumber` so that it would give you 5 zero's

Comment: `01000023456789100002130G7` also has 5 zeroes between 1st and 7th position, where does OP write that zeroes needs to be all consecutive?

Comment: no, where is 5 zero's between the 1st and 7th position in your example? 2nd position has the digit 1

Comment: There is 1 zero before `1` and 4 zeroes after `1` so total 5 zeroes and position is still between 1 and 7.

Comment: This is a matter of interpreting the range as inclusive or exclusive. Without further input from the OP both interpretations are equally valid IMO.

Comment: @anubhava "1 zero before 1". so why do you calculate the first position?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I am including both position 1 and position 7 since otherwise position 2 to 6 can have only 5 zeroes. And in if we exclude position 1 and 7 then solution would be as simple as: `awk 'substr($0, 2, 5) == "00000" {$4="9010"} 1' file`

Answer (score 0):

This awk should work:

```
awk '{s=substr($0, 1, 7); gsub(/0+/, "", s)} length(s)<=2{$4="9010"} 1' file
60000123456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   1000
60000023456789100002130G7 2.01408190151529E+28 1E+31 9010
```

To get the formatting right pipe with `column -t`:

```
awk '{s=substr($0, 1, 7); gsub(/0+/, "", s)} length(s)<=2{$4="9010"} 1' file | column -t
60000123456789100002130G7  2.01408190151529E+28  1E+31  1000
60000023456789100002130G7  2.01408190151529E+28  1E+31  9010
```

**EDIT:** To get formatting right without using `column -t`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{s=substr($0, 1, 7); gsub(/0+/, "", s)} length(s)<=2{$4="9010"}
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF)?OFS:RS}' file
60000123456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28    1E+31   1000
60000023456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28    1E+31   9010
```

Comment: column -t is not working on my side. Is there any possible command to get the right formatting? Thanks

Comment: You mean `column` binary is not available on your system?

Comment: it gives me this error: filter_sundr.sh[24]: column:  not found

Comment: That means `column` isn't available for you. Can you get it on your system since it is a standard utility.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. But isn't any other way to do it?

Comment: Other ways to get formatting right are there using printf but that is lot of extra code.

Comment: check updated answer to get formatting right without using `column`

Comment: The updated answer you've provided gives a uniform formatting but originally, the formatting of record is like this 60000023456789100002130G7<5spaces> 2.01408190151529E+28<3spaces>1E+31<2spaces>9010<10spaces>NN .. I am sorry to make you confused.

Comment: For that you need to use column binary.

Comment: Also please remember your original question, which was not about formatting the output.

Answer (score 0):

Avinash Raj and Perreal, why do you assume that the five zeros are consecutive?

Avinash Raj, why do you ignore the first and the seventh digits?

```
awk '{ S=substr($0,1,7); gsub("[^0]","",S); if (length(S)==5) $4=9010; print }'
```

To keep the formating spaces:

1) assuming three spaces from one field to the next one:

```
awk '{ S=substr($0,1,7); gsub("[^0]","",S); if (length(S)==5) $4=9010; print $1"   "$2"   "$3"   "$4}'
```

2) Assuming a non-negative integer number ([0-9]+) at the end of the input line:

```
awk '{ S=substr($0,1,7); gsub("[^0]","",S); L=$0; if (length(S)==5) sub("[0-9]+$","9010",L); print L}'
```

3) Assuming there are only four fields in the input line.

```
awk '{ S=substr($0,1,7); gsub("[^0]","",S); L=$0; if (length(S)==5) sub($4"$","9010",L); print L}'
```

4) To retain the original full-length space separators:

```
awk '
 {
  S=substr($0,1,7)
  gsub("[^0]","",S)

  if (length(S)!=5) {
    print
    next
  }

  $4=9010

  N=split($0,GAP,"[^ ]+")
  L=""
  for(i=1;i<=N;i++) L = L GAP[i] $i
  print L
}'
```

Comment: how do I ignore the 1st and 7th digits?

Comment: @Jdamian thanks, this works. but i encountered a problem on the spacing.. below is the output:                                          60000123456789100002130G7   2.01408190151529E+28   1E+31   1000
60000023456789100002130G7 2.01408190151529E+28 1E+31 9010

Comment: @Jdamian thanks, this works. but i encountered a problem on the spacing. On the original record, there are 3 spaces between fields but the output gives: 60000023456789100002130G7 2.01408190151529E+28 1E+31 9010 (one space in between). How can I retain the original space format? Thank you

Comment: The procedure to retain the space format is either: 1) printing field by field separated by three spaces 2) Assuming the the fourth field is the last one, substitute the number at end of the input line for the string 9010. I'm gonna extend my answer to include this format issue.

Comment: @Perreal, I'm sorry for my mistake -- you don't forget the 1st and 7th digits.

Comment: @Jdamian is it not possible to retain the original format? The original record i have to filter have no fix number of spaces (there are field separated by 3 spaces and the other 10 spaces) Also, it is not the last field. Thank you again.

Comment: @Aronpaulnievera, I think the format issue is beyond your original question. Nevertheless, it is possible to retain the original format and I'm going to extend my answer to include the code