# If else condition inside awk

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, awk

I want to save the filtered output on $FILES > $TEMP_FILE and the unfiltered output to  $FILES > ${DST}/${FILES}. My problem is my "if" condition do not work.

```
 awk '                                          
 NF {                                           
   data  = substr ($0, 1, 14)                 
   count = gsub (/0/, "", data)               
    }

 {if (count==12) print $FILES > $TEMP_FILE;
  else print }' $FILES > ${DST}/${FILES}
```

Furthermore, given this string
      90050200075560218800000514223500GS
how can I replace 22nd and 23rd digit (00) by 10th and 11th digit (75)? My output will be    90050200075560218800075514223500GS

Comment: What does your input data look like? Have you tried doing a `{print count}` in between the first block and the second?

Comment: This part works,   awk '                                          
 NF {                                           
   data  = substr ($0, 1, 14)                 
   count = gsub (/0/, "", data)               
    }

 {if (count==12) print }' $FILES > $TEMP_FILE    ... but when I added the else condition, I got an error.

Comment: Where are `$FILES` and `$TEMP_FILE` defined? Also, as I said before, it would be helpful to show a sample of your data.

Comment: You should not create multiple user accounts. Questions related to [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396032/count-of-zeros-between-the-1st-and-14th-digit-by-using-grep/25396083#25396083) should be asked there itself.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that inside the (single quoted) `awk` script, `$FILES` and `$TEMP_FILE` are references to `$0` because `FILES` and `TEMP_FILE` are uninitialized variables and hence equivalent to 0.

What you seem to want might be:

```
awk -v TEMP_FILE="$TEMP_FILE" '
NF  {
    data  = substr ($0, 1, 14)
    count = gsub (/0/, "", data)
    }
    { if (count == 12) print data > TEMP_FILE
      else print
    }' $FILES > ${DST}/${FILES}
```

This should print the modified data to the name specified by shell variable `$TEMP_FILE` which is passed to `awk` via the `-v TEMP_FILE="$TEMP_FILE"` arguments, and print unmodified data to standard output and hence `${DST}/${FILES}`.  I note that despite its name, `${FILES}` must list a single file for the I/O redirection to work sanely.

AFAICT, the script processes lines with at least 14 characters.  If there are 12 zeros in the first 14 characters, then the data is supposed to be printed to one file; otherwise, the unaltered line is supposed to be printed to the alternative file.  If in fact the unaltered line is supposed to be printed in both cases (just to different outputs), then drop the `data` from `print data > TEMP_FILE`.

Comment: what if I only want to filter records if the first character is equal to "5" ? How can i add to the condition you've provided?

Comment: Before the `NF` pattern, add `$0 !~ /^5/ { next }`?

Comment: The output on TEMP_FILE prints all the records starting with "5" and not the filtered records only. How about that?

Comment: Put the condition in the block with the `if/else`; perhaps `if ($0 ~ /^5/) print $0 > TEMP_FILE` and then perhaps an `else` before the current `if`.  The specification is a bit vague still — but you can tighten it up and ensure it produces the correct answer by placing the test at the right point in the code for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mind, I have another question. Given this string 90050200075560218800000514223500GS, how can I replace 22nd and 23rd digit (00) by 10th and 11th digit (75)? My output will be 90050200075560218800075514223500GS.

Comment: That's pretty much wholly unrelated to the original question.  I'm not sure whether there's a better way than using multiple `substr` operations.  Assuming the string is in `str`, then maybe: `modstr = substr(str, 1, 21) substr(str, 10, 2) substr(str, 24)`.

Answer (score -1):

Its a shell command line problem.

You need to escape the `";"` like so `"\;"`.

Or just remove it as per comments below.

Escaping definitely works on cygwin ksh -- may be different on a "real" k shell.

Comment: Are you sure of that?  The script is a single-quoted string, so there is no escaping anything in it.

Comment: Works for me when I escape it!

Comment: No need to escape the `;`, in fact you can just remove it, if its at the end of the line.  If you escape it, you get this message `^ backslash not last character on line` where `^` points at the back slash in `\;`